# Where should I ask a question about terminology that casual users may find hard to understand?

Tags: support, scope

I want to ask a question about what terms are often difficult to understand for casual users in computer science, more specifically for creating guides.

Where should I ask questions about what basic terminology is around that casual users might not know?

Does this kind of question belong on Stack Exchange, or is it too broad?

Comment: No, but it's allowed on Google.

Comment: You might be able to get away with asking it on cseducators.

Comment: @Oleg I don't know about that. People seem to like downvoting this question (It's a metaboard and I asked a question about if something's okay to ask; the answer is obvious to other people but I saw it as a weird gray area) so I doubt I could get away with it elsewhere in the website.

Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that would be a Primarily Opinion Based question, as you're asking people for opinions.  It would also be Too Broad if you were able to remove the subjectivity.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I am making a guide and wanted to ask for help. Good to know that I shouldn't be asking around here.

I thought it was opinion based so I decided to ask here first.